# 'require': cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' (LoadError) when running `rails server`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm running a clean install of Ruby 2.2.1 on Windows 8.1 with DevKit. After the installation I run:

```
gem install rails
rails new testapp
cd testapp
rails server
```

leaving everything else at default.

The process fails at the last line when, instead of running the server, I get the error message

```
in 'require': cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' (LoadError)
```

It happens every time and I've looked around and tried everything I found to fix it, but nothing so far has worked.

What is the problem here and how do I get a simple test Rails app to work?

Comment: have you run `gem install nokogiri` ? This will at least tell you why it wasn't installed as a dependency of Rails.

Comment: run `bundle install` on rails directory

Comment: It's a problem with Ruby2.2

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Nokogiri doesn't support Ruby 2.2 on Windows yet. The next release will. See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

Nokogiri doesn't support native builds (e.g. with devkit) on Windows. Instead it provides gems containing prebuilt DLLs.

There's a discussion which you may want to join or watch on the topic of devkit build support here: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1190

Comment: Thanks for the info, that clears it up. For now I'll just move to linux to work on rails.

Comment: Even though I am on MacOS and had an issue with nokogiri on a completely different version, this made enough sense to try and upgrade my Ruby. It worked for me, so I'm leaving this comment to say to anyone not on Windows: Try upgrading ruby if you are spinning up a new project like I was.

Answer (score 39):

1. First, uninstall the version of Nokogiri you currently have with:

   ```
   gem uninstall nokogiri
   ```
2. Download [Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 (x64)](https://github.com/paulgrant999/ruby-2.2.2-nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-x64-mingw32.gem/raw/master/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32.gem) or [Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 (x86)](https://github.com/paulgrant999/ruby-2.2.2-nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-x64-mingw32.gem/raw/master/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32.gem)
3. Install this version locally using:

   ```
   gem install --local C:\Users\$user$\Downloads\nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32.gem
   ```

   or if you're running 32bit Ruby:

   ```
   gem install --local C:\Users\$user$\Downloads\nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32.gem
   ```

   The path may differ depending on where you downloaded the file to.

Try to start the server again using `ruby bin\rails server`, and it should work.

Comment: Beautiful, it works! Still stupid that Nokogiri doesn't support 2.2.x or above on Windows though...

Answer (score 36):

I got Nokogiri running with Ruby 2.2 on Windows 10 with a mix of Mike Dalessios and Julios answer:

1. Look for the latest version of Nokogiri in [Nokogiri's github repo](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256).
2. Run `gem uninstall nokogiri`.
3. Add `gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.6.7.rc"` to your Gemfile.
4. Run `bundle install`.
5. Run `bundle update nokogiri` if bundle has locked Nokogiri at some version.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

## Fix

1. Bundle install (gets Nokogiri files)
2. Browse to `ruby_dir\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\nokogiri-1.6.6.2\ext\nokogiri`
3. Open `extconf.rb`
4. Add `dir_config('iconv').any? or pkg_config('libiconv')` to `#376`
5. [Download `MinGW64` & `MSYS` folders from Mega](https://mega.nz/#!c4tGRSTb!FJtcq25l-QMsNltCxllMhc1IGqORvap8xv8gWxSUbDA)
6. Add them to `PATH` in Windows (remove `Devkit` path refs - it doesn't work)
7. [Download `libxml2`,`libxslt`, `iconv` libraries](https://mega.nz/#!Zw1QCSDa!Zm39QTKS2nAHh7vZxt7TJeZk8U-Wg8UFCVi6abDn2oo) (or [here](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/))
8. Run `ruby extconf.rb --platform=ruby --n --use-system-libraries` referencing downloaded libraries
9. Run `make`
10. Run `make install`

---

## Steps

**Bundle Install**

First step is to *bundle*.

This will put the `nokogiri` gem on your machine without running the pre-packaged compiler (which mostly doesn't work in Windows).

This will show Nokogiri as *installed*:

[image]

**Browse**

Browse to the `nokogiri` folder, to find `ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb`:

[image]

**Open `extconf.rb`**

... and add `dir_config('iconv').any? or pkg_config('libiconv')` to `#376`

[image]

Standard Nokogiri installs "rely" on the `libxml2` inclusion of `iconv` - we need to explicitly define it, otherwise `iconv.h is missing` errors will occur.

**Add Toolchain**

Don't use `devkit` for this - it doesn't work.

You need `MinGW`:

[image]

I have zipped my exact `MinGW64` and `MSYS64` folders [on Mega](https://mega.nz/#!c4tGRSTb) (key: `!FJtcq25l-QMsNltCxllMhc1IGqORvap8xv8gWxSUbDA`):

[image]

**Add to PATH**

This gives access to `gcc` & `make` (both required):

[image]

Remove the `devkit` ref from your path, and add the following:

> - MINGW64_PATH/bin
> - MSYS64_PATH/bin

**Download Libs**

I have added the libs to Mega:

[image]

You will unzip them here:

[image]

All the libs are from [this source](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/).

**Run `extconf.rb`**

Once libs are on your system, you can run `ruby extconf.rb` to configure the build:

[image]

> **32bit**
>
> `ruby extconf.rb --platform=ruby -N -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/32bit/libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86 --with-xml2-include=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/32bit/libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86/include/libxml2 --with-iconv-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/32bit/iconv-1.14-win32-x86 --with-xslt-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/32bit/libxslt-1.1.28-win32-x86`
>
> **64bit**
>
> `#64
>   ruby extconf.rb --platform=ruby -N -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/64bit/libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86_64 --with-xml2-include=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/64bit/libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86_64/include/libxml2 --with-iconv-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/64bit/iconv-1.14-win32-x86_64 --with-xslt-dir=C:/Dev/Dependencies/Ruby/lib/nokogiri/64bit/libxslt-1.1.28-win32-x86_64`

**`make`**

[image]

This may create errors / warnings, as long as it says "`Error 1 (ignored)`", it should be okay.

Following that, use `make install`:

[image]

Then browse to your Rails installation and run `rails s`:

[image]

---

## Explanation

To give context:

Ruby 2.2+ on Windows doesn't compile the *extensions* Nokogiri requires.

The *extensions* of a gem are the extra dependencies (libraries) it uses.

They are built when you *install* the gem:

[image]

---

**[Extensions](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/)**

Lack of extensions is preventing Nokogiri from running.

Extensions exist in the `ext` folder of a gem ([you can read about them here](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/)):

[image]

`Mysql2`,`RMagick`,`PGSQL`, `Nokogiri` etc *all* use extensions/libraries.

This is why - on Windows - you have to use custom switches (`--with-opt-dir`) when installing the gem. This gives Ruby / the shell / (`cmd`) the required `lib` / `include` directories required to build the gem's files (it's the equivalent of how [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) works).

On `Linux`/`Mac`, these directories are managed with the respective package managers (`brew`/`apt-get`). Windows does not have this, so you have to install the extensions manually.

Because Windows does not have a standard set of libraries, you have to download them yourself. You also have to *build* them yourself (which is tricky).

The fix for Nokogiri install is to use the right libraries and build tools to get the gem installed.

---

**Build**

The difference with Ruby 2.2+ is the gem will "install" without showing any exceptions. You think it has installed, only to find Rails does **not** load (hence the `nokogiri/nokogiri.so` error).

This means you have to make sure you have the files on your system, and run the compiler to install them.

The above documentation should show you how to do that.

Comment: I tried logging in with the key you provided but it said the url was no longer :( Any chance of getting the necessary components from you?

Comment: Sure, let me fix up the repo

Comment: MINGW64 / MSYS64 - https://mega.nz/#!c4tGRSTb!FJtcq25l-QMsNltCxllMhc1IGqORvap8xv8gWxSUbDA

Comment: Just getting the libs sorted, I think Mega deleted them

Comment: Regardless, the gem should work with the later versions of ruby. I was just interested in getting it working properly (no hacks) on Windows, hence my post. If you're using the later versions of Ruby, you should be able to install Nokogiri with no issues

Comment: Thanks - I am working on a friends project using Ruby 2.3.0 and they are mostly using OSX but have had nokogiri issues... I'm using win7 on an old 2009 i3 HP lappy and from [the answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33410164/5225057) I got something functional but I much prefer not having to modify the Gemfile - thanks!!

Comment: NP If you want, I have some time and we could try and get it working over chat or something

Comment: It's really a compilation issue; Windows can't compile anything without the correct libraries

Comment: Also, your explanation of what's involved in getting it to work properly really helped me understand what is going on with rails and gem management. I'm new to dev w/rails and it's taking some getting used to!

Comment: Yeah I'd almost given up with rails on windows!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131964/discussion-between-mr-kennedy-and-richard-peck).