# When I start the server in Ruby On Rails it exits as soon as it starts and sometimes doesn't even start, just gives an error

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick, web-development-server

This is the error message in Windows:

```
   C:\Users\USER\Sites\new_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogir
.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw3
/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw3
/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/r
ils/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/r
ils/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/r
ils.rb:11:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/r
ils.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-r
ils.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-r
ils.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/r
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.r
:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/USER/Sites/new_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (requ
red)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Users\USER\Sites\new_cms>
```

Comment: The first line tells you what to do: (Re)-install Nokogiri, optionally using the system libraries instead of the bundled ones: `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nokogiri** doesn't have [binaries for `Ruby 2.2.1` available for the `mingw32` platform](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1259) due to some problems with [cross compiling `Ruby 2.2.1` for the `rake-compiler-dev-box`](https://github.com/tjschuck/rake-compiler-dev-box/pull/20).

Since **Nokogiri** doesn't natively compile on *Windows*, the only fix is to [downgrade to `Ruby 2.1.5`](https://bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller/2.1.5). Once the next patch level of `Ruby 2.2` is released hopefully the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
rvm ruby-2.2.0 gem update --system
```

Looks like ur nokogiri path broken

ps edited on ur rvm version

Comment: firt of all i am on windows and there's no rvm for windows and i reinstalled nokogiri. still this error message:

Comment: How to update the system path to libraries? Could you answer in some detail?

Comment: Omg, i find it!! look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999906/require-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-loaderror-when-running . U have ruby version 2.2 and nokogiri does not support 2.2