# Ruby on windows causes error Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Trying to run ruby on my Windows 7 machine whenever i go to rails s or rake db:migrate i get the following error Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext.

My ruby version is 2.2.1 my rails version is 4.2.0 and the bcrypt version is 3.1.10. All the gems install correctly when i run bundle install however whenever i try to rake it gives me that error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try with `ruby-bcrypt` version `3.1.9` ; this [thread on github](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/102) seems to imply that the bug was fixed for that specific version. Maybe `3.1.10` has a regression.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use what it says here: https://www.alib.jp/entries/bcrypt_ext_load_error_on_ruby21x

```
C:\> gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bcrypt
C:\> cd (path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> ruby extconf.rb
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make install
```

Comment: This is bizarre. I used this answer, but then `make install` put the resulting `.so` file in `C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.2.0\i386-msvcrt`. The gem was not looking there for it, according the error message. So, I copied that manually to `C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1.rc1-x86-mingw32\lib` and it worked fine. Different version of gem, as you can see, but maybe it will help the downvoter.

Comment: On windows platform, this can download DevKit-mingw64 on ruby installer can devkitvars.bat. for making gcc build

Comment: I don't understand this solution except for the gem install part. How do I know what is my path to gems root?

Comment: It's in `c:/ruby_dir/lib/ruby/gems/[[ver]]/gems`

Comment: It is saying ` make: command not found what's make command, how do I let cmd know what make is
`

Comment: You need to get `make.exe` which is either from `mingw` or `devkit` - if that makes sense I can explain it more specifically :)

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same problem in Window 8.1 64bit  , Ruby 2.3.3 64bit , Rails 4.2.10.

My quick solution :

Step 1 : Remove all bcrypt in gem : `gem uninstall bcrypt` ( choose option 3 if existed (remove all))

Step 2 : Install bcrypt again : `gem install bcrypt`

Then check version of bcrypt : `gem list bcrypt`

Step 3 : In Gemfile of your project, add :    `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw]`    
notice : change the suitable version of your bcrypt (my version : 3.1.11)

Step 4 : Run command in the path of your project :  `bundle install`

Step 5 : Remove the unneeded  bcrypt :
Run command : `gem uninstall bcrypt`  
You can see some version of bcrypt , you should keep one version : bcrypt-[your-version] . (Remove all version : bcrypt-[your-version]-x64-mingw32 . In mycase , remove : bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32)

Restart Rails sever , done

I think this proplem because when we install bcrypt , we didn't specify 64bit or 32bit , it is not compatible with window or ruby ( 64bit or 32bit )

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10, bcrypt 3.1.11 now works, [checked in 24144](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24144)

steps:

1. shut down all rails servers
2. uninstall all versions of bcrypt
3. manually install v3.1.1  (`gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.11'`)
4. update gem files of projects

current versions

- ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
- OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586

Comment: When you install bcrypt, use this command: `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby` this has worked for me a number of times.

Answer (score 4):

The dirty quick workaround is to install the mri version with

`gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`

worked for me.

`Fetching: bcrypt-3.1.11.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.11`

source:
[topac](https://github.com/topac) commented on Apr 17, 2015
https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/116

Answer (score 1):

[Rich Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext/33593911#33593911) solution worked for me with a small update. Make sure the devkit is included in the environment path.(Check it by typing path in the command prompt) If its not included,you need to add the [devkit/bin and devkit/mingw/bin](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) paths to your PATH var.

Otherwise - make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found - error will be thrown while you make the file.

Once the error is fixed, then i am able to make the file and the bcrypt_ext issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the compiled gem binaries don't contain binaries for `Ruby 2.2.1`. This is because there is a problem with cross-compiling Ruby with a Windows target. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29219698/527152) for more details.

The **best** alternative is to downgrade to `Ruby 2.1.5`.

You can try to compile the gem yourself, but that's a totally different beast. In some cases, like `nokogiri`, it's not even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, getting an ssl cert problem when trying to install gems so i got to go from there.

Comment: That's a completely different issue. [Here is the fix](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#installing-using-update-packages-new)

Comment: Thanks for the guide, but seems like alot of the gems in this bundle might not be compatible with windows. getting the same error now on pg_ext

Comment: The `pg` gem should work. People work really hard on getting things to work for Windows users, but things aren't always perfect. Which version of the `pg` gem are you using? If it's [version `0.17.x` try upgrading to `0.18.1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617779/pg-pg-ext-load-error-in-rails).

Comment: Yeah problems do a occur. as per your advice i was running on 0.17.x upgaded to 0.18.1 no luck.

Comment: how do I downgrade to ruby 2.1.5?