# Cannot run puma server for my application because of bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bcrypt-ruby

My machine is a Windows 8 32 bit machine and I have ruby 2.1.8.

I am facing a problem when I am trying to open my app in puma and rails server. I am even unable to run `bundle install`. The erorr is:

```
in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.
  - C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1.rc1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.so (LoadError)
```

and the bundle install error is:

```
could not find gem 'bcrypt (=3.1.5 rc1) x64-mingw32' in any of the gemfile ruby 2.1.8
```

same problem happens also for bcrypt version 3.0.0 and 3.1.1 also

My Gemfile is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.9'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

gem 'plivo'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete', :git 'https://github.com/AyushRuiaHW/rails-jquery-autocomplete.git'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false 
end

gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'hypdf', '~> 1.0.12'
gem 'currency-in-words'
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'Instamojo-rb'
gem "kaminari"
gem "rails-erd"
gem 'levenshtein', '~> 0.2.2'
gem "lol_dba"
gem "bullet", :group => "development"
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'puma_worker_killer'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'puma'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1'
gem 'aws-sdk-resources', '~> 2'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

ruby "2.1.8"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on windows causes error Cannot load such file bcrypt\_ext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext)

Answer (score 0):

delete your old gem 'bcrypt-ruby',and insert

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your old gem and update your gemfile with following

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.0'
```

and run `bundle install` , then restart your server.

You might also want to try deleting your gemfile.lock and re-running `bundle install`.

**OR**

you can install gem bcrypt directly from command line as following :

```
gem install --version='3.1.0' bcrypt-ruby
```

then run `bundle install`