# Add Gem 'wdm' to your GemFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, wdm

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BegJs.png)

I have tried running the following command in git bash

```
rails g scaffold_controller oragnizationsController
```

And I get the error in the picture. 
I have tried multiple solutions:

1- Tried running

```
gem install wdm
```

2- Tried running

```
bundle install
```

3- I have tried adding

```
gem 'wdm',  '~> 0.1.0'
```

and

```
gem 'wdm',  '~> 0.1.1'
```

since I read that 0.1.0 ain't working anymore. 
But the problem hasn't been solved yet. I am using windows 10, ruby 2.3.3, rails 5.1.4

Comment: Literally all I did was google the error message and click the first link: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142#issuecomment-252508115

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a unix-based system rather than Windows for development, if at all possible. Developing on Windows is generally a pain; you'll run into lots of annoying issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message about `wdm` is misleading here. It seems to be just a notice/warning.

If you look closer, you'll see that the actual error message is printed in the line below that. It says:

`cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)`

Then see here: [Ruby on windows causes error Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext/33593911#33593911)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall wdm gem and put it to the gemfile like this:

```
gem 'wdm' if Gem.win_platform?
```

Or like the error tells you