# Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am running rails in windows 10 and when I try to log in I'm getting bcrypt load error. I used to get this error before but I used to solve it. But this time I am not able to. I have tried all the solution by installing bcyrpt gem but nothing is working for me. I am stuck with this. Can anybody help me

I have referred this before

[Ruby on windows causes error Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext/33593911#33593911)

Comment: Can you please provide ruby and rails versions

Comment: @Shrikant1712 I'm using Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, try to use  bcrypt 3.1.11

1. Uninstall older bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby
2. Install it again by adding following line in Gemfile

   `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'`
3. Then bundle install