# Loading error:bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-10, bcrypt-ruby, rails-5.1.6

I have created a admin panel using ROR platform. Now whenever I try to login I'm getting this error :

> Cannot load such file bcrypt_ext

I have come across this error in the past but used to rectify it by uninstalling and reinstalling it using the below steps:

1. shut down all rails servers
2. uninstall all versions of bcrypt
3. manually install v3.1.1 (gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby)
4. update gem files of projects

But this time nothing works. I have referred many links but none helped.

i'am working using Windows 10, Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.3.3.

i have used devise gem for login function and my user model looks like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 devise :database_authenticatable,#, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 
 end
```

admin.controller

```
class AdminController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ?

Comment: @NicoHaase There is nothing wrong in code. Because it was working before and i referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext/33593911#33593911 every time but now it is not working

Comment: @Vishal  yes i have installed ubuntu on windows

Comment: @Amy install `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev`

Comment: It's fine that there is "nothing wrong in code", but without some sample code, we're not able to reproduce the problem

Comment: @NicoHaaseI have used devise gem for login functions. I have edited the post. plz, check the code.

Comment: @Vishal  I installed that but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem's version you're trying to install might not be available yet on Windows. Have you tried installing a previous version of bcrypt? Or take a look at https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/139, multiple solutions are provided.

Comment: The link helped me a lot. Thanks for that.I solved the issue.