# nokogiri issues with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3-ruby

I wanted to install Ruby on Rails to learn more about how to programming with Ruby on Rails as I know there is a demand for this web application framework.

So, I downloaded the latest ruby and the dev kit for 64 bit which is present on the website.

I also installed sqlite3.

Then I was trying to create new blog.

I did:

```
cd blog/bin

rails server
```

I got this error:

```
[Error Log][1]


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bBG8G__J_CN3JPTERZRTF5RDQ/view?usp=sharing
```

I have also had similar issues with sqlite3 and played with the Gem file,

Did I miss something with the installation?

I am completely novice on this issue, at least until now :-)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: I do not recall bundle install I used what ever was written on the website step by step..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999906/require-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-loaderror-when-running

Comment: It basicslly saying move to linux to work with rails...

Comment: What is the output of `gem install nokogiri`?

Comment: I just installed Ruby 2.1.x to solve this problem on Windows.