# How to fix too many Nokogiri versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, nokogiri

What does this error message mean, and how can I set up this project so that the server will function?

I'm using Windows 7, Ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.2.0, and `bundle install` passes.

`gem list` reports:

```
nokogiri (1.6.8.1 x86-mingw32, 1.6.7.2 x86-mingw32, 1.6.6.2 x86-mingw32)
```

Per "['require': cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' (LoadError) when running `rails server`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999906/require-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-loaderror-when-running)"
should I be specifying  Nokogiri in the Gemfile? Currently it is not specified.

I don't know what to make of this error report:

```
PS C:\Users\user_name\web_page> rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'

        ...

        from bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Should I uninstall and reinstall Nokogiri?

Comment: You should uninstall the older versions of Nokogiri and leave the latest, then add that to your bundle. Windows presents special problems when dealing with non MS languages so don't be surprised if there are still issues. http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows has information about its installation on Windows that might help.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you for the edits & reference. Yes, I am reconsidering my windows lappy for rails... If you put this in an answer I will accept it once I get a moment to read the link & implement your suggestions.

Comment: @theTinMan after an uninstall of all versions, I gem installed the latest (1.6.8.1) but upon `bundle install` >>> `Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2.` ??? I assume there is something telling it it needs that version? Same LoadError upon `rails s`